# How to disable keyboard shortcuts pop up in Juno?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon, release-juno

Every time that i press the "Windows" Key, this Keyboard Shortcuts pops up. There's a way to disable this?

// btw this is my first time here so I'm sorry if I ask wrong

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Pop UP]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Settings > Keyboard and change the default behavior for the ⌘-key to disabled.

⌘-key is the super-key or the 'windows'-key. 
See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key) for the origin of the symbol.

Comment: For anyone else that overlooks it at first: this setting is on the `System Settings->Keyboard` `Layout` tab (not `shortcuts` tab, which is what I expected).

Answer (score 0):

Use dconf-editor

go to:
org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior.overlay-action

and change the value to empty as below:

[image: dconf editor]

to install dconf:

sudo apt install dconf-editor

or find this in AppCenter.

PS.
It took me many months to figure out how to do this. :(

Sorry but I think it is as the most annoying and pointless function of the elementary OS, at least it should be using a less intrusive shortcut.

Comment: @dietervdf proposed a better way in my opinion. But yours is also good, thanks!