# Remove shortcut preview

Tags: release-hera, keyboard-shortcuts

In Hera, sometimes I press the super key to activate a shortcut and then I change my mind.
However an annoying keyboard shortcuts preview pane appears. Pressing the super key again gets rid of it. But is there a way to make it not appear in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings > Keyboard and change the default behavior for the ⌘-key to disabled.

⌘-key is the super-key or the 'windows'-key. See wikipedia for the origin of the symbol.

[source](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17168/how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-pop-up-in-juno)